# Possible Corollary to Fernique's Theorem

Tags: probability-theory, normal-distribution, stochastic-analysis

I was following Stochastic PDE literature, mainly from Da Prato & Zabczyk. And I browsed a bit through the lecture notes by Martin Hairer.

Now, what I have understood from Fernique's Theorem is that: it provides an upper bound for $\mathbb E \Bigg[\mbox{exp}\Big(\frac{||X||_{V}^{2}}{18\mbox{R}^{2}}\Big)\Bigg]$, where $X : \Omega \to V$ be a mapping which satisfies for all $\phi \in V^{'}$ that $\phi(X):\Omega \to \mathbb R$ is a centred Gaussian Random Variable and $\mbox{R}$ is a positive number satisfying $\mbox{R} \geq \mbox{inf} (\{r \in [0,\infty) : \mathbb P(||X||_{V} \leq r) \geq \frac{9}{10}\})$, $(V,||\cdot||_{V})$ being a separable $\mathbb R$-Banach Space and $(\Omega , \mathcal F , \mathbb P)$ is a usual probability space.

Now, the question is, can we say something replacing this $\mbox{R}$??

i.e. I want to prove or disprove: for every above such probability space and $\mathbb R$-Banach Space $V$, and for every above such $X$, there exists (As of now, I am yet to prove/find out any counter-example) $\epsilon \in (0,\infty) $ satisfying $\mathbb E \Bigg[\mbox{sup}_{r \in (-\infty, \epsilon]}\mbox{exp} \Big(r ||X||_{V}^{2}\Big)\Bigg]$ < $\infty$.

Any kind of help towards a conclusion is welcome.

Thank you!!

P.S. :- As from the remark $2.8$ at page - 39 of Da-Prato and Zabczyk, "For a sufficiently small positive $\lambda$ we have $\int \limits_{E} e^{\lambda |x|^{2}}\mu(dx) < +\infty$."

So, I think safely we can conclude that:

> For every probability space $(\Omega , \mathcal F , \mathbb P)$, every separable $\mathbb R$-Banach Space $(V,||\cdot||_{V})$ and every centred Gaussian distributed random variable $X:\Omega \to V$ , $\exists$ a real number $\epsilon \in (0,\infty)$ such that: $$E \Bigg[\sup_{r \in (-\infty, \epsilon]}\exp \Big(r ||X||_{V}^{2}\Big)\Bigg] < \infty.$$

Is my thinking is alright??

Comment: Your question is quite unclear. What do you mean by "replacing this $R$"? Your last conclusion is correct, but this is exactly what Da Prato and Zabczyk say.

Comment: Thanks a lot.. The above mentioned "$R$" is defined via the infimum. I was asking if I can make the last "highlighted" conclusion ("So, I think safely we can conclude that:... ") as a corollary of Fernique's theorem where we can guarantee the existence of some "$\epsilon$" such that the expectation is finite.

Comment: Well, I wouldn't call this "corollary", as this is exactly what Fernique's theorem says.

Comment: yeaah.. !! true.. I can't disagree!! :-)